# Oracle Query to sum a column by every date range in another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to write a query in my project where I want sum of a column on every date range of another table (for ORACLE database).

TABLE1 – It has number of pax booked on every date:

```
DT          NO_OF_PAX
--------    ---------------
01-JAN-14    10
02-JAN-14    5
03-JAN-14    8
05-JAN-14    5
:
:
28-DEC-14    20
30-DEC-14    9
31-DEC-14    15
```

TABLE2 – It has lot of date ranges:

```
ST_DT        END_DT
---------   ------------
01-JAN-14    31-JAN-14
01-FEB-14    28-FEB-14
12-JAN-14    15-FEB-14
:
:
01-NOV-14    20-NOV-14
01-DEC-14    31-DEC-14
```

Now I need to write query that it should display SUM(NO_OF_PAX) from TABLE1 for every date range of TABLE2. Please advise how should I write.

As both have no common column, I dont know how to join both the table. I wrote as 
`SELECT SUM(TABLE1.NO_OF_PAX) FROM TABLE1, TABLE2
WHERE TABLE1.DT BETWEEN TABLE2.ST_DT AND TABLE2.END_DT`

It fails with not a single-group group function.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct SQL:

```
SELECT T2.ST_DT, T2.END_DT, 
(
    SELECT SUM(T1.NO_OF_PAX)
    FROM TABLE1 T1
    WHERE T1.DT BETWEEN T2.ST_DT AND T2.END_DT
) NO_OF_PAX
FROM TABLE2 T2
ORDER BY T2.ST_DT ASC
```

See on SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2e9e9/1/0

Answer (score 0):

RUN this and let me know your result ( TESTED)

```
SELECT A.ST_DT, A.END_DT, SUM(A.NO_OF_PAX) FROM
(
    SELECT t2.*, t1.NO_OF_PAX
    FROM Table1 t1,
         Table2 t2
    WHERE t1.DT BETWEEN t2.ST_DT AND t2.END_DT
) A
GROUP BY A.ST_DT, A.END_DT
```

Comment: this gonna fail, you forgot "select from" and you are grouping by but he wants to know in a range of date for each row.

Comment: @Andrew Paes: I tested using your SQLFiddle. It worked. Return the same result as your.

Comment: @Loc Apologies I forgot to specify that TABLE2 can have duplicate date ranges. I still want them to display as duplicate data with sum of number of pax. So this failed in that because of GROUP BY func.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way

```sql
SELECT st_dt, end_dt, COALESCE(SUM(no_of_pax), 0) total
  FROM Table2 t2 LEFT JOIN Table1 t1
    ON t1.dt BETWEEN t2.st_dt AND end_dt
 GROUP BY st_dt, end_dt
```

Sample output:

```
|     ST_DT |     END_DT | TOTAL |
|-----------|------------|-------|
| 01-JAN-14 |  31-JAN-14 |    28 |
| 12-JAN-14 |  15-FEB-14 |     0 |
| 01-FEB-14 |  28-FEB-14 |     0 |
| 01-NOV-14 |  20-NOV-14 |     0 |
| 01-DEC-14 |  31-DEC-14 |    44 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b2bb5/4)** demo